# What are these tiny insects?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Italy (Emilia Romagna), and my house, seasonally in spring, is full of these guys, someone knows their name and if they could represent a problem?
They are very tiny slightly less than 0,5 cm including the antennae.
[image: the insect on my hand]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be *Anthrenus verbasci*.

These insects are not dangerous, but they can damage carpets, clothing and furniture.

[image]